# How do I slow down the transition of my image changing if I created a new image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, styles, setinterval

I created an image in JavaScript but I want it to fade when the function is called, however I'm a bit confused on how to do this. When I tried setting the transition it doesnt work. Can someone please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="yellow.js"> </script>
</head>
<style>



</style>


<body>

<img src="tmac.jpg" alt="TmaC" width="175px" height="220px" class="tracy"/>
</br> </br>

<li class="thead" onclick="slow()"><a href="#">News</a></li>
<script>
function changeStyle() {
cool = document.getElementsByClassName("tracy");

tmag = cool[0].src="tmagic.jpg";
}
function slow() {
slows = setInterval(changeStyle, 3000);

slows.style.transition="2s";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: rad about transition [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) ... you need more than a duration, you need at least a property as well - also, not sure you can "transition" img src changes

Comment: so the does indeed change, but i want it to fade in as if its blending into the old image. @JaromandaX

Comment: CSS transitions are irrelevant when changing img src attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: sounds like you're trying to fade one image into another. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23w8ufLd/4/)

A couple. Your line breaks should read `<br/>`, not `</br>`. Also, why are you using an "li" element to hold the link? LI elements are generally used within ordered or unordered lists.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```js
  document.getElementById('fade').addEventListener('click', function () {
   document.getElementById('cat').style.opacity = .0;
   document.getElementById('cat2').style.opacity = 1;
  })
```

```css
#cat {
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
}

#cat2 {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSVdqOi4n85V3ryq1cf-5GJC7ezxjZNmqAoSVGNvCILoWgsEe6FYP7YpoY" alt="TmaC" width="175px" height="220px" id="cat"/>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTIwESPol4bmt3xUdAAYq8OmKeua5T7UAtvdLB154Nhs888PhvP" alt="TmaC" width="175px"  height="220px" id="cat2"/>
<button id="fade" style="margin-top:250px">Fade</button>
```

Comment: so i understand how to fade an image out but i want it to transition into the other image i created in the JavaScript....kind of like when the cat fades i would want a new cat to show up...theoretically speaking.